# rename headers of several multifasta files

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I have multi-fasta files with names starting with `P` (for example `PANS_1_2`, `PANS_1_5`, `PANS_200_2`, `PANS_200_2`).

These files have headers like this

```
>1_1262659_105.258519
>2_809301_107.252177
>3_422941_112.146787
>4_413692_100.238323
```

I am trying replace the headers of these files with the `filename_ctg1`. If a input fasta file is `PANS_1_2` then the headers in the output file (PANS_1_2.fasta) should be:

```
>PANS_1_2_ctg1
>PANS_1_2_ctg2
>PANS_1_2_ctg3
```

I tried the following code:

```
for sample in P*;do echo -en $sample;awk '/>.*/{sub(/[^>]*/,">$sample_ctg"++i)}1' $sample;done > $sample.fasta
```

The mentioned script is not resulting in the desired output.

Comment: please note that only one answer you can chose as accepted answer not multiple answers, so when you chose an answer as accepted you confirm that your question is resolved by that answer you marked as accepted. I'm writing this because you changed the accepted answer almost on your all questions recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU sed in a for loop.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
for sample in ./P*; do
  knt=$(grep -c '^>' < "$sample") || continue
  seq -f ">${sample}_ctg%g" "$knt" > "$tmp"
  sed -e "/^>/R $tmp" -e '//d' < "$sample" > "$sample.fasta"
done
```

- get the count of headers in a given sample file.
- construct the headers to be added based on the sample file name and header count from previous step.
- Replace each header line with the next line read from the constructed headers file of the previous step.

Comment: I slightly modified the code to get a change in output                                     
tmp=$(mktemp)
for sample in ./P*; do
  knt=$(grep -c '^>' <"$sample") || continue
  seq -f ">lcl|${sample}|ctg%g" "$knt" > "$tmp"
  sed -e "/^>/R $tmp" -e '//d' < "$sample" > "$sample.fasta"
done                                                                                                                                                I am getting the following header >lcl|./PANS_1_10|ctg1 How can ./ be removed from the output file header?

Comment: @Gavin remove it from this `./P*`  occurring in the very first line.

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==1{ close(out); inc=0; fileName=substr(FILENAME,3); out=fileName".fasta" } 
     /^>/{ $0= ">"fileName"_ctg"(++inc) }
     { print > out }' ./P*
```

`FILENAME` is a *awk* variable that hold the current processing input file name; we set it into `fileName` to get ride of first `./` from it; prefix dot-slash in files name `./` is used to avoid problems with files named like `PANS=1_2` for instance as `awk` do reading these kind of *strings* as a *variable* when these come after `awk` codes;

everything inside double-quotes "..." are literally strings;

`++inc` is pre-incremental arithmetic expression is used to number each header and will reset back to *0* for next input file with `FNR==1` we used.

The `$0` is represent the entire line/record in `awk`, so we update (`$0= ...`) those lines that start with `>` character, with ">" character then *fileName* followed by `_ctg` string and incremental number.

third line we `print` what current line value is to a file name that its name is same as current *fileName* read by *awk* and append ".fasta" string into it also.